# how to show using integration $\int_1^M x^{n+1}e^{−x}$ by part that for any real M> 1?

Tags: definite-integrals, contour-integration

After having the

\begin{align*}
\int_1^M &x^{n+1}e^{−x} dx  \\
&= −M^{n+1}/e^{M}+1/e+\int_1^M (n+1)x^{n} e^{−x}dx  \\
&= [x^{n+1} e^{x}]-\int_1^M e^{-x} (n+1)x^{n} e^{−x}dx  \\
&= M^{n+1} e^{M} - x^{n+1} e^{x} \int_1^M e^{-x} + ne ^{-x} x^{n} + e^ {n}dx  \\
&= M^{n+1} e^{M} - x^{n+1} e^{x} \int_1^M [-ne^{-x} + nx ^{n-1} - e^{-x} + e^ {n-1}]dx
\end{align*}

Using part integration, Is there something I missed? The solution says that we can verify

so, $$\int_1^M x^{n+1}e^{−x} dx=M^{ } e^{M} - x^{n+1} e^{x} \int_1^M [-ne^{-x} + nx ^{n-1} - e^{-x} + e^ {n-1}]$$

Comment: What does $[x^{n+1}e^x]$ mean in your second line? Why isn’t it $[x^{n+1}e^{-x}]?$

Comment: And how do you get $e{-n}$ anywhere?

Comment: Check out the incomplete gamma function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function
It gives more general results. You can probably find some derivation of the result you're after.

Answer (score 1):

If $$A_{n+1}=\int_1^M x^{n+1}e^{-x}$$

Let $u=x^{n+1}, dv =e^{-x}\,dx,$ you get $du=(n+1)x^n$ and $v=-e^{-x}.$

So:

$$\begin{align}A_{n+1} &=-M^{n+1}e^{-M}+e^1 +(n+1)\int_1^M x^ne^{-x}\,dx\\
&=e-M^{n+1}e^{-M}+(n+1) A_{n}
\end{align}$$

Also, $A_0=e-e^{-M}.$

So:

$$A_{n+1} =(n+1)!\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \frac1{k!}\left(e-M^{k}e^{-M}\right)$$